# Error when get value in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a code js;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
init_test(500,100);
document.write(init_test[0]);
</script>
```

but output is wrong, it is not result is 500. How to fix ?

Comment: It helps to keep the JavaScript error console open where error messages are displayed.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you intended `init_test` to be an array. Currently you are attempting to call a function named `init_test` with two arguments. What you wanted was this:

```
var init_test = [500, 100]; //init_test is an array with 2 elements
document.write(init_test[0]); //Write the element at index 0
```

If that's not what you intended, and `init_test` is a function that you haven't shown in your question, and that function returns an array or an object, you need to assign the return value to a variable and then access the index of that:

```
var returned = init_test(500, 100);
document.write(returned[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You tried to access on an variable which is maybe only declared within the function 'init_test()'. Define the variable outside your function and I'm sure you will get the correct value.